# I keep getting "list index out of range" in Python when the list has the correct index

Tags: python, list

I am new to Python and am getting the list index error, when I shouldn't. 
I have the following variable:

```
date_array = ['2001','15','1']
```

I can access the first index. I can only access the last index, if I try something like this:

```
date_array[-1]
```

I get "list index out of range" error whenever I try:

```
date_array[2]
date_array[1]
```

I am attaching the complete code below for your reference:

```
import csv
import datetime
import re
marketReader = csv.reader(open('test.csv', 'rb'))
i=0

for row in marketReader:
    cust_id = row[0]
    date = row[1]   # Is a text. Ex: '2002-1-1'
    spent = row[2] 

    date_array = (re.split('-',date)) # Provides an array ['2002', '1', '1']
    year = date_array[0]
    month = date_array[1]
    day = date_array[2]

    # Is weekday?
    weekday=datetime.date(year,month,day).weekday()

    if i==200 and row[0]>3 :
        break
    pass
    #print(day)
    i += 1
```

Any help will be really appreciated! This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Where exactly does the error appear?

Comment: Are you sure you len(date_array) is always 3? Add a check to make sure it is

Comment: Are you sure the date in your CSV file is in the format you think it is? Do you need to use [dateutil](http://niemeyer.net/python-dateutil)  to parse it first?

Comment: Print the value of `row` and of `date_array` when the exception occurs. That should lead you in the right direction. If it doesn't, then paste those values into your question for us to see.

Answer (score 2):

Simple answer is that date_array does not always have 3 elements. If you're going to index the list directly, add a check to make sure that the length is adequate.

```
if len(date_array) < 3:
    print('date_array too short')
    # do something else
```

or alternatively, wrap the index operations in a try block

Comment: Thanks a lot JimB! I assumed my data is consistent - a terrible assumption!

Comment: program defensively, and *always* assume data will be inconsistent :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `date` contains a date string separated by hyphens? If it does, this should work:

```
>>> import re
>>> date_array = (re.split('-',date))
>>> date_array
['2002', '1', '1']
>>> date_array[0]
'2002'
>>> date_array[1]
'1'
>>> date_array[2]
'1'
```

Perhaps you could add `print date` to verify that the `date` value is what you think?  Also, including the traceback in your answer would help us.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys! Yeah, its exactly what you guys said - I assumed consistent data (that is date is always present and in the correct format). Thanks!

Comment: @bigGreenGrad, here at StackOverflow, there two built-in mechanisms for expressing thanks for helpful answers. You can click the up-arrow for any helpful answer, and for the best answer you can click the check-mark to indicate that you have 'accepted' this answer. It's not required, of course, it's just a courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

If you had the correct index Python would never complain about it. If it complains, it's wrong. It's *that* simple.

Now figure out why the list is too short. You could **print** out the array and immediately see what's wrong.